# mySQL merge Child to Mater in same table

Tags: mysql, merge, unique, mysql-workbench

I am currently working on RDMS database where I am looking to insert unique emails to a record in a table. the person table contain a auto generated Id along with a foreign key from the persons table (personid). The person email table contains the following columns:
personemailID, email, personid
The current person table contains 1 million records and from those million records we have email addresses stored in the email table. One record can have multiple emails stored against them, and sometimes duplicate person  can be created in the person table, which means we would have two person records with duplicate  email addresses against. I have managed to write a query which identifies duplicates, and now I need merge one record into another in same table for example,

```
            personemailID   email   personid
            1   stackoverflow@stackoverflow.com 1
            2   stackoverflow1@stackoverflow.com 1
            3   stackoverflow@stackoverflow.com 2
            4   stackoverflow@stackoverflow.com 2
            5   testing@stackoverflow.com 2
```

So as you can see I have two candidates that are duplicated, however, there are unique email addresses against each record. Say for argument case my Master record is person 1 and child record is person 2.  I want to insert only the unique email address from child record into master record, ignoring duplicates.
I have tried using mysql Insert Ignore, however, that only seems work when the data is in two different tables, however, when in the same table it duplicates the record as for  each email address the ID is unique.

I am at lost as to how this can be achieved so any help or advice is appreciated.  I have worked through many solutions provided, however, nothing that works for me.

```
            insert into _test_person_email(defaultemail,
                        EmailAddress,
                        EmailDescription,
                     PersonID,
                     EmailType)

            SELECT 
                defaultemail,
                EmailAddress,
                EmailDescription,
                PersonID,
                EmailType
            FROM
                _test_person_email t1
                    JOIN
                (SELECT 
                    a.PersonID ParentID, b.duplicateID ChildId
                FROM
                    _test_person_email a
                JOIN (SELECT 
                    e.PersonID duplicateID, EmailAddress duplicateIMail
                FROM
                    _test_person_email e) b ON b.duplicateIMail = a.EmailAddress
                    AND b.duplicateID <> a.PersonID
                GROUP BY a.EmailAddress) t2 ON t2.ChildId = t1.personid
```

The outcome of the requirement should be the master record containing its exiting emails along with the unique emails from child record (2).

```
            personemailID   email   personid - Master Record
            1   stackoverflow@stackoverflow.com 1
            2   stackoverflow1@stackoverflow.com    1
            6   testing@stackoverflow.com   1
```

The person email table for the child record will not have any data stored against it as it would be deleted once merged. The master record has new row inserted, as  personemailID is auto incremented, the ID number changes, and also the person id will be inserted as the master record ID.

I understand the insert ignore will not work in this instance as each email address against a record has its own unique key, therefore, insert ignore will add the same email to master record due to having a unique primary key. The two person table with email will never have a duplicate primary key, therefore, my focus point will in-fact be the email address itself.

Comment: Please provide [Complete information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @AlvaroNiño, apologies I not sure what it is I am required to provide. I need to merge records where there is a duplication, but only unique records should be inserted  in to the table for the master record (personid). So what when I look at the master record, I will have the exiting records along with the new records from the child record. the child record will then be deleted.

Comment: Please try to provide an example of your desired output

Comment: @AlvaroNiño oh right sorry.  I will edit my initial query with the desired outcome. Apologies.

Comment: Please can someone help me with this. Apologies if its not very clear. i tried my best to write down clearly what m,y problem and what the outcome should be.